# What would this function return if I called it with an index that didn't exist? EnumerableSet.sol

Tags: revert

I'm looking at this function in OpenZeppelin's EnumberableSet.sol contract...it deletes an item in a set by taking the last item in the array and moving it to the slot of the deleted item and then popping the last slot in the array off. I have two questions...first, what would happen if I called this function with an index that didn't exist? Would it revert?

Second, why does `toDeleteIndex` = `valueIndex` - 1...I would think it would just be `valueIndex`

```
function _remove(Set storage set, bytes32 value) private returns (bool) {
        // We read and store the value's index to prevent multiple reads from the same storage slot
        uint256 valueIndex = set._indexes[value];

        if (valueIndex != 0) {
            // Equivalent to contains(set, value)
            // To delete an element from the _values array in O(1), we swap the element to delete with the last one in
            // the array, and then remove the last element (sometimes called as 'swap and pop').
            // This modifies the order of the array, as noted in {at}.

            uint256 toDeleteIndex = valueIndex - 1;
            uint256 lastIndex = set._values.length - 1;

            if (lastIndex != toDeleteIndex) {
                bytes32 lastValue = set._values[lastIndex];

                // Move the last value to the index where the value to delete is
                set._values[toDeleteIndex] = lastValue;
                // Update the index for the moved value
                set._indexes[lastValue] = valueIndex; // Replace lastValue's index to valueIndex
            }

            // Delete the slot where the moved value was stored
            set._values.pop();

            // Delete the index for the deleted slot
            delete set._indexes[value];

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your two questions:

1. What would happen if you called this function with an index that didn't exist? Would it revert?

- No, the function as written would not revert if called with an index that doesn't exist. Instead, it would simply return false, indicating that the element with the provided value (represented by bytes32 value) was not found in the set. Because, if you called with an index that didn't exit, valueIndex will be equal to zero, that leads to return false.

2. why does toDeleteIndex = valueIndex - 1...I would think it would just be valueIndex

- The reason **toDeleteIndex = valueIndex - 1** is to account for the fact that array indices are **zero-based** in Solidity. That means, if the element to delete is at index **valueIndex**, its actual position in the array is **valueIndex - 1**. Therefore, when swapping the element to delete with the last element in the array, we want to move the last element to the position of the element to delete, which is at index **valueIndex - 1.**